# Which Class is missing in the following program?

Tags: java, arrays

```
class Test
{
int unique_element(int arr[],int n)
{
    int result=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int sum=0;
        x=(1<<i);
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j]&x)
                sum++;
        }
        if(sum%3)
        {
            result |= x;
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
    return(result);
} 
public static void main(String[] args){
    int arr[]={3,1,1,9,3,1,3,9,9,5};
    N=arr.length;
    System.out.println(unique_element(arr[],N));
    }
}
```

Program for every element appears 3 times in a given `arr` except 1 element. Logic is correct but I'm getting error in print statement like `.class` is expected.

> Test.java:28:error: '.class' expected
> System.out.println(unique_element(arr[],N));

and i'm getting error in if statement --> if(arr[j] & x){ sum++;}

> Test.java:298: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean
>
> ```
>       if(arr[j]&x)
> ```

Comment: The condition inside "if" should either evaluate to true or false. Are you intending to use "&&" instead of "&" ? Similarly you should use "sum%3==0"  or  "sum%3!=0" instead of "sum%3"

Comment: @sukesh I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling the method "unique_element" from static method.
To solve the problem either declare the method "unique_element" to be static or call it     under the context of object

```
Test t = new Test();
int arr[]={3,1,1,9,3,1,3,9,9,5};
int N = arr.length;
t.unique_element(arr,N);
```

Please notice, To pass array, You should call "unique_element" with "arr" as argument rather than "arr[]".

Comment: Can also be simplified to `new Test().unique_element(arr[], N);`

Comment: @locus2k Absolutely, I just assumed the OP is beginner and might get confused with one liner call.

Comment: Would you really call `unique_element(arr[],N);` hint: `[]`

Answer (score 2):

You forget to declear the data type of `N`. Also either need to declare the method `unique_element` -> `static` or create a new instance of `Test`.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int arr[]={3,1,1,9,3,1,3,9,9,5};
    // declear N with data type
    int N=arr.length;
    System.out.println(new Test().unique_element(arr,N));
}
```

Update:

> i'm getting error in if statement --> `if(arr[j] & x){ sum++;}`

Actually `if(arr[j] & x)` is `c` style syntax in Java a `boolean` expression is expected inside `if` statement. You can change it:

```
if((arr[j] & x) !=0){ sum++;}
```

The same thing is also true for: `if(sum%3)`. This should be:

```
if(sum%3 !=0)
{
    result |= x;
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although these answers given will get you the correct answer I would opt to take the different approach and actually make `unique_element` a static method, meaning that there will only ever be one instance of it. A static method is perfect for this because it requires no state, two inputs and one, output.

Example:

```
package org.stackoverflow.thread_safe_account;

public class Test {
    public static int unique_element(int arr[],
                                     int n) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int sum = 0;
            x = (1 << i);
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (arr[j] & x)
                    sum++;
            }
            if (sum % 3) {
                result |= x;
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
        return (result);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {3, 1, 1, 9, 3, 1, 3, 9, 9, 5};
        N = arr.length;
        System.out.println(Test.unique_element(arr[],N));
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the use of "org.stackoverflow.thread_safe_account;" this package?

Comment: it was just the name of the package I put the sample code in?